# Creating a program that does the same fuction as a Java Set

Tags: java, set

I'm trying to creating create a program that does the same functions as the Java Set. I wrote this to handle intersection:

```java
public class mySet
{
    private Set<Integer> yourSet=new HashSet<Integer>();
    private mySet set;

    public HashSet <Integer>  intersection(HashSet<Integer> setb)
    {
        HashSet<Integer> copy;
        copy=setb;
        yourSet.retainAll(setb);
        System.out.println(copy);
        return copy;
    }

}
```

When I do `setA.interception(SetB)` SetA is an object of mySet while SetB has to be a HashSet. I want both SetA and SetB to be an object of mySet

I've tried changing HashSet setb to mySet setb but then the retainAll does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class MySet<T> {
    private Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

    public MySet() {}

    private MySet(Set<T> set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public MySet<T> intersection(MySet<T> b) {
        Set<T> newSet = new HashSet<>(set);
        newSet.retainAll(b.set);
        return new MySet<>(newSet);
    }
}
```